# Lazarus IDE: Importando imagens no projeto

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Ultimamente migrei do Delphi XE6 para o Lazarus IDE, e como não estou acostumado com a nova plataforma gostaria de saber como posso importar imagens, vídeos e outros recursos no projeto e assim usá-los (sem a necessidade de utilizar um diretório específico do sistema operacional).

Aproveitando-se da mesma situação, seria viável criar um arquivo do tipo zip e armazenar ou simplismente criar um pacote no próprio projeto contendo esses recursos (e como poderia estar fazendo a criação deste pacote e a referência dos recursos no código Pascal).

**OBS:** Pretendo utilizar as imagens em um objeto TImage e definir na propriedade Picture.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui deixo um tutorial com a solução para a minha pergunta (contém algumas adaptações que fiz para facilitar o processo).

**Tutorial**

Primeiramente o **Lazarus IDE** tem uma ferramenta chamada **lazres.exe**, localizada na pasta **tools** do Lazarus (**X:**\**diretório_do_lazarus**\tools\lazres.exe) - substitua o que está em negrito pela unidade e diretório de instalação do Lazarus.

Depois de localizá-lo estarei explicando brevemente o funcionamento do LazRes.

**Introdução ao LazRes**

Seu funcionamento é por linhas de comando e permite a criação de arquivos de extensão **LRS (Lazarus Resources)** - uma espécie de criador de pacote permitindo adicionar todos os recursos que desejar (como imagens, áudios, vídeos, arquivos em gerais, etc).

Para a **criação do pacote** deve ser passado **dois parâmetros** para o **LazRes.exe**, o **nome do pacote LRS** e os **recursos**:

```
lazres.exe <nome_do_pacote.lrs> <arquivo1 arquivo2 arquivo3...>
```

**Etapa 1: Preparando a criação de pacotes com um arquivo de lote**

Essa etapa pode ser ignorada caso saiba manusear o prompt de comando e também o lazres.exe

Copie e cole o código abaixo no bloco de notas. Você deve salvá-lo no mesmo diretório do lazres.exe (**X:**\**diretório_do_lazarus**\tools) com o nome de **LRSBat.bat**

**LRSBat.bat**:

```
@echo off
cls
pushd %~dp0
set l=^call lazres.exe 
%l%
echo.
set /p f=Nome do Pacote ^(.lrs^):
set f=%f:.lrs=%
set f=%f%.lrs
@echo.
set a=
set p=
@echo.
echo Arraste um arquivo de cada vez e pressione ENTER para adicionar mais.
echo Quando finalizar digite /f/ e pressione ENTER para gerar o pacote final.
:addArquivos
set /p "a=Arquivo: "
if "%a%"=="/f/" (goto:criarLRS)
if exist %a% (set p=%p% %a% )

goto:addArquivos

:abort
exit

:criarLRS
echo ---------------------------------
%l% %f% %p%
echo.
echo ---------------------------------
ECHO Fim.
pause>nul
exit
```

**Etapa 2: Criando seu primeiro pacote (usando o LRSBat.bat)**

Execute o arquivo **LRSBat.bat** como administrador e siga os procedimentos que estão na tela. Caso obteve êxito será criado um arquivo LRS no mesmo diretório com o nome escolhido.

**Etapa 3: Implementando o arquivo LRS (pacote) no projeto Lazarus**

**Copie e cole o arquivo LRS na pasta do seu projeto.**

Com o projeto aberto no Lazarus e no editor de código da `unit` escolhida, você estará incrementando as seguintes linhas:

```
uses ..., LResources;

. . .

{ Ao final do projeto antes do end. incluir as linhas abaixo }
initialization
 {$I nomedopacote.lrs}

end.
```

Isso vai permitir a compilação do pacote **nomedopacote.lrs** junto com o executável do projeto.

**Etapa 4: Usando um arquivo do pacote LRS no projeto**

Por exemplo, para a adição de um arquivo de imagem do pacote em um componente de imagem do Lazarus, siga os procedimentos abaixo. Suponha que o componente de imagem seja `componenteDeImagem` e o `nome_do_arquivo` faz referência ao nome da imagem do pacote (sem a extensão):

```
componenteDeImagem.Picture.LoadFromLazarusResource('nome_do_arquivo');
```

Independentemente do componente a ser trabalhado, caso queira utilizar um arquivo do pacote no projeto deve fazer uso do método **LoadFromLazarusResource**.

**Referências**

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Resources